Запятая оборота "в сравнении"
С этого времени эволюция оценки персонала в
России и СССР в сравнении со странами Европы и США пошла в разных направлениях.
Выделяется ли "в сравнении со странами Европы и США" запятыми в этом случае?

Правильно:
С этого времени эволюция оценки персонала в России и СССР, в сравнении со странами Европы и США, пошла в разных направлениях.
Пояснение
Розенталь § 20, пункт 2
В общем случае обособление обстоятельственных оборотов с производными предлогами является факультативным, и здесь нужно учитывать влияние различных факторов. В данном случае это распространенность оборота и позиция в середине предложения.
По семантике оборот можно соотнести обособленным условным придаточным: если сравнивать со странами Европы и США.  Поэтому актуализация оборота представляется обоснованной.
